# Trigger to prevent update when Flag value is 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trigger

I need help with a trigger to prevent update on any column except for column Flag (it can be updated) when Flag value is 1 on the below table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tmp (Id INT, Type INT, TranDate DATE, Flag INT)
INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES (1, 2, '2017-04-24', 0)
INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES (2, 4, '2017-04-27', 1)
```

I've tried with the below code but doesn't work correctly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Prevent_Update_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Tmp]
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF  EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Tmp t JOIN inserted i ON t.Id=i.Id AND t.Flag=1)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('You can not update when Flag value is 1', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo_Tmp_trg_AU
ON dbo.Tmp
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM Deleted AS Del
        WHERE
            -- Originally, flag was 1
            Del.Flag = 1
            AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                -- Column(s) aside from Flag have changed
                SELECT
                    Del.[Type],
                    Del.TranDate
                INTERSECT
                SELECT
                    Ins.[Type],
                    Ins.TranDate
                FROM Inserted AS Ins
                WHERE
                    -- Same Id
                    Ins.Id = Del.Id
            )
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You can not update when Flag value is 1', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
```

This assumes the `Id` column cannot be updated (e.g. it is an `IDENTITY` column).

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this and it will work. I tested it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Prevent_Update_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Tmp]
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF  EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Tmp t JOIN deleted i ON t.Id=i.Id AND i.Flag=1)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('You can not update when Flag value is 1', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Test:

```
UPDATE tmp SET flag=10
WHERE id =2
```

Error message:

> ```
> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Prevent_Update_Trigger, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 20]
> You can not update when Flag value is 1
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
> ```

Comment: The question says the Flag column (alone) *can* be updated when it is 1.

Comment: Thank you SqlWorldWide! It works. Now, I'd only need to exclude Flag column from that trigger i.e. Flag can be updated.

Comment: you are welcome.  Thanks for letting me know.  I assumed so but @PaulWhite 's point is valid. It was not clear in the question.

Comment: This works for me, but the issue is that even though you rolled back the tran, the IDENTITY was increased. I know I could do a CHECKIDENT to fix this, but it is scary, I might screw up the sequence. Yes I am using this for Insert too.